# Sales data : Plot number of ordered each item over time

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have dataframe with time-series data and want to plot number of each item over time.

```
       date    item      ordered 
1 01-05-2020      1           1 
2 01-05-2020      1          23 
3 03-06-2020      2           4
4 03-07-2020      2           5
5 04-09-2020      3           4

df_new = df.groupby(df[['date','item']])['ordered'].sum().reset_index()
df_new.plot()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) before ploting, also dont convert `DatetimeIndex` to column by `reset_index` before ploting:

```
df_new = df.pivot_table(index='date', columns='item', values='ordered', aggfunc='sum')
print (df_new)
item           1    2    3
date                      
01-05-2020  24.0  NaN  NaN
03-06-2020   NaN  4.0  NaN
03-07-2020   NaN  5.0  NaN
04-09-2020   NaN  NaN  4.0

df_new.plot()
```

Your solution:

```
df_new = df.groupby(['date','item'])['ordered'].sum().unstack()
print (df_new)
item           1    2    3
date                      
01-05-2020  24.0  NaN  NaN
03-06-2020   NaN  4.0  NaN
03-07-2020   NaN  5.0  NaN
04-09-2020   NaN  NaN  4.0

df_new.plot()
```

Comment: both solution plottig the graph and giving error `AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute '_is_all_dates'
`

Comment: @alex3465 - What is pandas version?

Comment: Updated the pandas solved the issue , thanks